# configure networkmanager to share internet

Tags: networking, network-bridge

I am connected to a WiFi Network with my laptop, now I would like to connect another device at my LAN port, so it can also use the internet connection I got over Wifi

How can I configure this in my network manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open Unity Dash, search Network, and open the resulting app.
2. Select your LAN adapter and then click "Options..." in the lower right corner.
3. Go to the "IPv4 Settings" tab.
4. Under the "Methods" dropdown, select "Shared to other computers."

That should hopefully do it.

[image: Example]

Comment: Great. This just works!